# How to write more number of pages bypassing Maximum pages set by journal template

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, page-numbering, debugging

```
%% LaTeX2e file `cmes.cls'
% Document class for publication in CMES
% LaTeX2e version 4.0 2000
%
% Copyleft 2008
%
% Standard Disclaimer Applies.
%

\ProvidesClass{cmes}[2007/01/28]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{book}
\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn}{book}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{geometry}
\else
  \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps}
  \RequirePackage[pdftex]{geometry}
\fi

\geometry{papersize={7in,10in},total={5in,7.5in},hmarginratio=1:1,vmarginratio=1:1}

\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{enumerate}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{natbib}


\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}





\setlength{\mathindent}{0em}
\gdef\pindent{0em}
\setlength\parindent{\pindent}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
\setlength\parskip{3pt}
\setlength\footnotesep{7.7pt}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{topnumber}{5}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\setlength\floatsep    {18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\textfloatsep{30\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\intextsep   {20\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\belowcaptionskip=4pt

%
%  bottom-of-page footnotes format
%  full width line and hanging indent
%
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
 \hrule width \columnwidth \kern 2.6\p@}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent=1em\hangindent=1em \def\baselinestretch{1.0}
\noindent\hbox to1em{\hss$^{\@thefnmark}$\,}\ignorespaces #1}
%
% page style
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{myheadings}\markboth{}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{section}{0}

%
%  heading
%
\newcommand {\markhead}[1]  {\gdef\thishead{#1}}
\newcommand {\markthishead} {%
\pagestyle{myheadings}%
\markboth{\hspace*{2em}\mbox{\small\@copyright}\hfill\underline{\small\@citeself}}%
{\underline{\small\@runningtitle}\hfill}}

%
%  Section headings
%
\newcommand\abstract[1]{%
\setlength\parindent{0em}%
\textbf{Abstract:\quad}#1
\setlength\parindent{\pindent}%
\par
\titleauthor{\string\cmesabs}{{#1}}
}

\newcommand\keyword[1]{%
\vskip 1.65ex%
\setlength\parindent{0em}%
\textbf{Keywords:\quad}#1
\setlength\parindent{\pindent}%
\par
\titleauthor{\string\cmeskey}{{#1}}
}

\newcommand\acknowledge[1]{%
\vskip 2.3ex%
\setlength\parindent{0em}%
\textbf{Acknowledgement:\quad}#1
\setlength\parindent{\pindent}%
\par
}

\def\appendix{
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \def\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}:}
}

\renewcommand\section{%
 \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-2.3ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {1.0ex \@plus .2ex}%
      {\reset@font\normalsize\bfseries\upshape}}%
\renewcommand\subsection{%
 \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
      {-1.65ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {0.8ex \@plus .2ex}%
      {\reset@font\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}}%
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
 \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
      {-1.45ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {0.8ex \@plus .2ex}%
      {\reset@font\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\fig}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{Tab.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{Eq.~\ref{#1}}


%
%  Bibliography
\let\mycite\cite
\renewcommand\cite[1]{\index{#1}\mycite*{#1}}


\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
 \def\@firstpg{\pageref{firstpg}}
 \def\@lastpg{\pageref{lastpg}}
 \markthishead
 \label{firstpg}
 \begingroup
   \if@twocolumn
     \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
       \@maketitle
     \else
       \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
     \fi
   \else
     \newpage
     \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
     \@maketitle
   \fi
   \thispagestyle{empty}\@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
 \global\let\thanks\relax
 \global\let\maketitle\relax
 \global\let\@maketitle\relax
 \global\let\@thanks\@empty
 \@firstpage
 \global\let\@author\@empty
 \global\let\@date\@empty
 \global\let\@title\@empty
 \global\let\title\relax
 \global\let\author\relax
 \global\let\date\relax
 \global\let\and\relax
}
\def\@maketitle{%
 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \null
 \vskip -2.5em%
 \mbox{\small\@copyright}\hfill{\small\@citeself}
 \null
 \vskip 4em%
 \begin{center}%
 \let \footnote \thanks
   {\textbf{\Large \@title} \par}%
   \vskip 1.5em%
   { \lineskip .5em%
     %\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
       \textbf{\@author}
     %\end{tabular}
     \par}%
   \vskip 1em%
   %{\large \@date}%
 \end{center}%
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\section*{\refname
       \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \setlength\labelsep{0ex}
           \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}%
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
     \endlist}
\gdef\runningtitle#1{\gdef\@runningtitle{#1}}
\gdef\@runtitle{}
\gdef\citeself#1{\gdef\@citeself{#1}}
\gdef\@copyright{Copyright \copyright \ \@cmesyear\ Tech Science Press}
\gdef\@citeself{CMES, vol.\@cmesvol, no.\@cmesno,
 pp.\@firstpg-\@lastpg,  \@cmesyear}
\gdef\cmesvol#1{\gdef\@cmesvol{#1}}
\gdef\cmesno#1{\gdef\@cmesno{#1}}
\gdef\cmesyear#1{\gdef\@cmesyear{#1}}
\gdef\@cmesvol{}
\gdef\@cmesno{}
\gdef\@cmesyear{}
%\gdef\@lastpg{}
%\gdef\@firstpg{}
\gdef\cmes#1#2#3#4{\cmesvol{#1}\cmesno{#2}\cmesyear{#3}\setcounter{page}{#4}}
\gdef\ignore#1{}
%
% .tit file
% 1. title/author info for the generation of table of contents
% 2. page number of the last page for the page numbering of next page
%
\def\@maketitleauthor{%
 \newwrite\@titleauthorfile
 \immediate\openout\@titleauthorfile=\jobname.tit
 \def\titleauthor{\@bsphack\begingroup
               \@sanitize
               \@wrtitleauthor}\typeout
   {Writing title/author info. \jobname.tit }%
 \let\maketitleauthor\@empty
}
\def\@wrtitleauthor#1#2{%
  \protected@write\@titleauthorfile{}%
     {#1 #2 {\thepage}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}
\@maketitleauthor
%
% 1. step the page counter to the first page
% 2. put author/title info into .tit
% 3. .tit to be used for the generation of table of contents.
% 4. propagate vol, no, year.
%
\def\@firstpage{%
 \stepcounter{page}\label{firstpg}%
 \global\let\affiliate\relax
 \titleauthor{\string\tocline}{{\@title} {\@author}}%
 \titleauthor{\string\cmesvol}{{\@cmesvol} \string\ignore}%
 \titleauthor{\string\cmesno}{{\@cmesno} \string\ignore}%
 \titleauthor{\string\cmesyear}{{\@cmesyear} \string\ignore}%
 }
\def\tocline#1#2#3{}
\def\cmeskey#1#2{}
\def\cmesabs#1#2{}
%
% 1. ensure the paper ends in even page number.
% 2. save the page number in .tit for as the starting point for the
%    next paper.  (.tit will be included at the begin of the next paper)
%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\lastpage{%
  \label{lastpg}%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\ }{}%
  \titleauthor{\string\prevpage}{}%
  }
\def\prevpage#1{\setcounter{page}{#1}}
%Proof watermark
\newif\ifproof
\prooftrue
\AtBeginDocument{
\ifproof
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\RequirePackage{color}
  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \newdimen\@tempdimd \newdimen\@tempdime
    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
    \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
    \setlength{\@tempdimd}{.50\paperwidth}%
    \setlength{\@tempdime}{.98\paperheight}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
    \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimd,\strip@pt\@tempdime){\textcolor[gray]{0.0}{\fontsize{11pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont \textit{CMES Manuscript http://www.techscience.com}}}
    \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
      \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{60}{\textcolor[gray]{0.9}{\fontsize{8cm}{16cm}\selectfont{Review}}}}
    }
 }
 \else
  \titleauthor{\string\prooffalse}{\string\ignore}%
 \fi
}
%
% superscript for authors
%
\def\affiliate#1{$^{#1}$}
```

% latex Text is as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{cmes}
            \cmes{1}{1}{2016}{0}

            \graphicspath{{./image/}}
            \runningtitle{Manuscript Preparation for CMES} 

            \title{Perfoe }
            \author{
            Prah \thanks{Department of },\
             Dai \affiliate{1}\
             Tom \affiliate{1}\
            and \
            Tomoy \affiliate{1}
            }
            \begin{document}
            \maketitle
            \abstract{
            This work presents
            }
            \keyword{Micro-electric effect}
            \section{Introduction}
            Piezoele
            \section{Formulation of }
            \subsection{Governin}
            The a;\\
            Electro
            whconstant.\\
            The strain respectively are given by
            d n ctively.
            \subsection{Finite eley}
            The stan
            \subsection{Timations}
            Various irequ step-by-step solution. 
            % subsection 3.1
            \subsubsection{Newc analysis}\label{newmark}
            IEq.(\ref{piezo_moton_eq_1}) \& Eq.(\ref{piezo_moton_eq_2}) wmark's time integration to Eq.(\ref{piezo_motion_eq_newmark_1}), we obtainWhere $\mathbf M$, $\mathbf C$, ${\mathbf{\hat K}}_{\mathrm {uu}}$ and  $ {^\mathrm{{t+\Delta t}}\hat {\mathbf F}}$  are the consistent mass matrix, daeleraated usingwhmed to 
            \subsubsection{Central difference integration method for linear dynamic piezoelectric analysis}\label{cd}
analysis.
            \subsection{F co actuators}\label{dyna_algorithms}
            ve c
            \subsubsection{MonolithN)}\label{MN}
            The mw of the M.
            \subsubsection{Block ration (BJN)}\label{BJN}
            \section{Analysis ctuators}
            In this secto
            \tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle, thick,draw,  text width=13em,align=center]
            \tikzstyle{rect_big} = [rectangle, thick,draw,  text width=16em,align=center]
            \tikzstyle{rect_med} = [rectangle, thick,draw,  text width=8em,align=center]
            \tikzstyle{line} = [very thick,red,draw, -latex']
            \tikzstyle{blank} = [node distance=1.6cm] %node dis=length of a line
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [rect] (top) {Piezoelectric bimorph actuators};
            \draw[thick,-] (0.0,-0.25) -- (0,-0.60);
            \draw[thick,-] (-3.0,-0.60) -- (3.0,-0.6);
            \draw[thick,->] (-3.0,-0.60) -- (-3.0,-1);
            \draw[thick,->] (3.0,-0.60) -- (3.0,-1);
            \node [blank, below of=top ] (blank1) {};
            \node [blank, below of=blank1, node distance=1.2cm ] (blank1) {};
            \node [rect_big, below =of top, yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-3.3cm] (left) {Bimroph actuators without metal shim \\ (or)\\Bimorph actuator};
            \node [rect_big, below  = of top,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=3.3cm] (right) {Bimroph actuators with metal shim \\ (or)\\Triple layer actuator};
            \draw[thick,-] (-3.50,-2.40) -- (-3.50,-2.80);
            \draw[thick,-] (-4.50,-2.80) -- (-2.50,-2.80);
            \draw[thick,->] (-4.50,-2.80) -- (-4.50,-3.10);
            \draw[thick,->] (-2.50,-2.80) -- (-2.50,-3.10);
            \node [rect_med, below = of left,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-1.8cm ] (left-left) {Series connection};
            \node [rect_med, below = of left, yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1.6cm] (left-right) {Parallel connection};
            \draw[thick,-] (3.50,-2.40) -- (3.50,-2.80);
            \draw[thick,-] (4.50,-2.80) -- (2.50,-2.80);
            \draw[thick,->] (4.50,-2.80) -- (4.50,-3.10);
            \draw[thick,->] (2.50,-2.80) -- (2.50,-3.10);
            \node [rect_med, below = of right,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-1.5cm ] (right-left) {Series connection};
            \node [rect_med, below = of right, yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1.9cm] (right-right) {Parallel connection};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{Classifuators }\label{bimorph classification}
            \end{figure}
            \noindent The exist Fig.\ref{Bimorph with metal shim in parallel connection}. 
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \subfloat[Bimorph in series connection]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.0in,width=2.20 in]{bimorph_series_no_metal.png} \label{Bimorph in series connection}
            } \qquad
            \subfloat[Bimorph in parallel connection]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.0in,width=2.20 in]{bimorph_parallel_no_metal.png} \label{Bimorph in parallel connection}
            }\\
            \subfloat[Triple layer  actuator  in series connection]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.0in,width=2.2 in]{bimorph_series_with_metal.png}\label{Bimorph with metal shim in series connection}
            }\qquad
            \subfloat[Triple layer actuator  in parallel connection]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.0in,width=2.20 in]{bimorph_parallel_with_metal.png}\label{Bimorph with metal shim in parallel connection}
            }
            \caption{Differenever piezoelectric bimorph actuators}{\begin{tikzpicture} \filldraw[fill=white,thin] (0,0)rectangle (0.5,0.1); \end{tikzpicture} is piezoelectric ceramic layer},  {\begin{tikzpicture} \filldraw[fill=black,thin] (0,0)rectangle (0.5,0.1); \end{tikzpicture} is metal layer}, $\uparrow$ is polarization direction. \label{bimorph_config}
            \end{figure}
            Due to the u
            %\vspace{-1.10 in}
            \subsection{Bending dry}
            Only
            \begin{align*}
             \omega_{r}^{(1)}=103.30\ \mathrm{rad/sec}                      
            \end{align*}
            \subsection{Results and discussion}
            f piezoelectric s.
            \subsubsection{Staticrs}
            Tsts of 134 and  240 s,  
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=2.5in,width=3.0 in]{static_itr_vs_error_BJ_BGS.eps}
             \caption{converg analysis}  \label{itr_convergence_static}
            \end{figure}
            s. Figure \ref{itr_convergence_static} shows the convergence results of partitioned iterative coupling algorithms (BJ and BGS) r.
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=2.5in,width=3.0 in]{BS_series_no_metal_Th_MN_Part_BJ_BGS.eps}
             \caption{Numeric deflection} \label{bimorph_bending_numerical}
            \end{figure}
            Figure olutioscribed in Figure \ref{bimorph_config}. 
            It follows frotioned coupling.
            \subsubsection{Dynamiltage}
            The  deflection to thon.
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=2.5in,width=3.0 in]{step_input_bimorph_series_no_metal_MN_BJN_BGSN.eps}
             \caption{The step response of bimorph actuator subjected to step bias V=1V with $\beta$=0.3025, $\gamma$=0.6 and $\rho_p$ =0} \label{step_resp}
            \end{figure}
            Figure s are obtained very efficiently by the coupled algorithms.
            \subsubsection{Dynamic analyoltage\\}
            The nung present( darix $\mathbf C$=100).
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \subfloat[$\Delta$t  for transient dynamic analysis at resonance frequency]{
              \includegraphics[height=2.0 in, width=2.2 in]{delta_t_study_107_MN_series_no_metal.eps} \label{delta_t_MN_107}
            } 
            \subfloat[$\Delta$t  for dynamic aarger than $\omega_r^{(1)}$]{
              \includegraphics[height=2.0 in,width=2.2 in]{delta_t_study_120_MN_series_no_metal.eps} \label{delta_t_MN_120}
            }
            \caption{$\Delta$t  for transient dynamic analysis to detect resonance frequency with the MN algorithm for AC voltage $V$=1V } \label{delta_t_MN}
            \end{figure}
             When thMN algorithm for dynamic analysis of bimorph actuators without metal shim (Figure \ref{Bimorph in series connection} ion.
            \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=30 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in, width=2.0 in]{w_30_mn.eps} \label{w=30}
            } \quad
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=95 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in,width=2.0 in]{w_95_mn.eps} \label{w=95}
            } \\
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=106 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in, width=2.0 in]{w_106_mn.eps} \label{w=106}
            } \quad
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=107 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in,width=2.0in]{w_107_mn.eps} \label{w=107}
            }\\
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=108 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in, width=2.0 in]{w_108_mn.eps} \label{w=108}
            } \quad
            \subfloat[Input frequency $\omega$=185 rad/sec]{
              \includegraphics[height=1.250 in,width=2.0 in]{w_185_mn.eps} \label{w=185}
            }
            \caption{Ardifferent frequencies with MN algorithm.}\label{mn_ac_resp}
            \end{figure}
            % It run successfully.
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        Please Copy and Paste From section {Introduction} to subsubsection {Dynamiltage}
            Run again- Result is, it compile correctly without any error %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            .Again Copy and paste From section {Introduction} to subsubsection {Dynamiltage}
            Result- It fails, because it exceeds 24 pages.
            \acknowledge{
            Add anent when appropriate.
            }
            \bibliographystyle{cmes}
            \bibliography{sample}
            \appendix
            \section{Example of appendix}
            Some text here.
    \lastpage
            \end{document}
```

I am unable to write a journal paper beyond 24 pages by using CMES journal template.someone help me. In the Latex Text file I excluded tikz files. You can find the Latex template here. Using the code I posted, I could compile without any error. But If I copy and paste more than two time, I can not compile.Please Copy and Paste From section {Introduction} to subsubsection {Dynamiltage}. Run again-: Result is, it compile correctly without any error.
   Again Copy and paste From section {Introduction} to subsubsection {Dynamiltage}, run again, Result:- It fails, because it exceeds 24 pages. help me with this.http://www.techscience.com/cmes/auth_instru.html

% Sample.tit file information

```
\tocline {Manuscript Preparation Instructions for Publishing in Computer Modeling in Engineering and Sciences (CMES)} { S.N. Atluri\thanks {UCLA, LA, CA, USA.},\ K.J. Bathe\thanks {MIT, Boston, MA, USA.}\ and \ K. Bathe\affiliate {2} } {1}
\cmesvol {1} \ignore {1}
\cmesno {1} \ignore {1}
\cmesyear {2016} \ignore {1}
\cmesabs { This document saration. } {1}
\cmeskey {Manuscript, preparation, typeset, format, CMES.} {1}
\prevpage  {6}
```

Comment: Isn't this not the same question like your other post?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, but In this post, I posted the original code, which I am using. I found that using \usepackage{tikz} creating a problem. Please help me.

Comment: You could have added that `\usepackage{tikz}` causes the trouble to the original problem (if that is really the problem at all)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer also when I uses \subfoat to create array of figure using \usepackage{subfig} creating the problem. If I don't use any figures (array of figure ) and flow chart using \usepackage{tikz}, I could create more than 60 or 100 pages. But If i include, my Flow charts and subfigures, it create problem. I am confused.

Comment: as already explained that class has no maximum page count. Please just fix the original question to have an example that shows the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Sir, Now after chatting with you, I could create any number of pages by deleting subfigures and flow chart. But When I use subfigure and my flow chart I have to include \usepackage{subfig} and \usepackage{tikz} packages, it creating problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I found this information here, http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/no-room-for-a-new-dimen-t10314.html  , I am glad to have your support. I am thankful to your kind support.  Yeah, Thank you for ur time.